# a function $f$ is differentiable in $\vec{0}$ if $f \circ \gamma $ is differentiable in 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves

Please help me solve this question:

let $f:R^n \rightarrow R$ be a function. **for all differentiable** curve $\gamma: [-1,1] \rightarrow R^n$ such that $\gamma(0) = \vec{0} \space$, $f \circ  \gamma :[-1,1] \rightarrow R^n $ is differentiable in $t=0$ . Prove that $f$ is differentiable in $\vec{0}$.

My way of thought here is to use the chain rule to say that that $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) =\nabla f(\gamma(0)) \cdot \gamma'(0)$ and than somehow to show that: $ \lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0} }\frac{f(x_1,...,x_n)-f(\vec{0})- \nabla f(\vec{0}) \cdot (x_1,...,x_n)} {||(x_1,...,x_n)||}$

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here' so it will be grat if you could have helped me.

thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this is true as stated. Did you mean to say that $f \circ \gamma$ is differentiable for **every** *differentiable* curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0) = \vec{0}$?

Comment: no... the question is for any $\gamma$ s.t $\gamma(0)=\vec{0}$

Comment: The hypothesis is still not quite clear. Do you mean that there exists some curve $\gamma$ such that $f \circ \gamma$ is differentiable at zero, or that for every (or for any) such (*differentiable*) $\gamma$, $f \circ \gamma$ is differentiable at zero?

Comment: what i meant is that **for every** curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0)= \vec{0} $ $f \circ \gamma$  is differentiable at zero

Comment: @PedroM. You were right. $\gamma$ is indeed differntiable