# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $\underline{0}$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, curves

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Lets assume that for every differetiable curve $\gamma:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\gamma(0)=\underline{0}$, $f\circ\gamma[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $t=0$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $\underline{0}$.

Denote: $g = f\circ \gamma$. Let $\gamma$ as described. By the chain-rule: $$g'(0) = D_f(\gamma(0))\gamma'(0) = 0$$.

But, can I have even do that? I mean, we don't know that $f$ is differetiable yet and I just used $D_f$.

More thoughts:

1. Choosing a specific $\gamma$.
2. Looking at the function from both $[-1, 0]$ and $[0,1]$.

Heck, lots of thoughts but couldn't put my finger on the solution.

Comment: Yes, you can't use the Chain Rule, exactly because it presupposes $f$ is differentiable, i.e., that $D_f$ exists.

Comment: OK, that's a progress :)

Comment: Same question (without answer) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106856/a-function-f-is-differentiable-in-vec0-if-f-circ-gamma-is-differenti.